# In an HTTP file transfer, how do I set the name and type of the resource?

Tags: perl, http

I'm building a proxy in Perl that checks if a user is allowed to access a specific file and if so, returns that file to the user. The user accesses the file by calling a URL of the form:

```
http://www.example.com/products?id=1234
```

If the user is authorized to access the file it should be returned to the user with the correct name and filetype. Here is the code I'm currently using to do this which doesn't seem to be working correctly:

```
my $file = "/path/to/file.tar.gz";
open FILE,qq|<$file| || die!;
print $cgi->header('application/x-gzip');
print <FILE>;
close FILE;
```

I'm sure there is something simple that I'm overlooking but how do I specify the name of the returned file and make sure the user's browser treats is as the correct filetype? To be clear, I don't want the user to be able to access the file on the server directly but instead want the Perl script to read in and then serve the file back to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`die!` is a syntax error. Replace your example code with:

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
⋮
print $cgi->header(…);
my $file_content = read_file '/path/to/file.tar.gz'
print $file_content;
```

The problem should instead be solved more efficiently with using [X-Sendfile](http://google.com/search?q=X-Sendfile).

Comment: @Dre lead me in this direction and your proposed solution is exactly what I ended up using. I agree that X-Sendfile is cleaner but we use Apache so it's not an option for us at the moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set a Content-disposition header

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=fname.ext
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Where do I add that? Is it something I pass to $cgi->header() or do I need to set it explicitly using some other CGI.pm function?

Comment: See http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI.pm/lib/CGI.pm#CREATING_A_STANDARD_HTTP_HEADER:

Comment: I updated the code to $cgi->header(-type=>'application/x-gzip',-attachment=>$file) and the naming is now working correctly which is great. However, the file returned seems to be corrupt and can't be unzipped. I've double checked the file on the server and verified that it's not corrupt. Any idea why the code above might be corrupting the out file?

Comment: Sorry about not noticing that before, you probably have a newline character in your file somewhere. -- http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1952 says how to grab the entire file at once.